# How to remove payment method from woocommerce admin email

Tags: email, templates, methods, woocommerce, payment

Cannot find how to remove payment method from woocommerce admin email.
Searched through the files for Payment Method, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you haven't done so, copy your woocommerce template files to your themes root as described in http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/.
Then, open a file that is responsible for building the email template. In my case it was (after copying it over) **/wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php**
Find the following lines of code

```
<tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                ?><tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</tfoot>
```

And add a condition to check if one of the labels contains Payment Method, like so

```
<tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                if ( $total['label'] != 'Payment Method:' ){
                    ?><tr>
                        <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</tfoot>
```

You can use this for other fields also